# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1) when trying predict a video using my model

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, lstm

Currently studying dee-learning

i am using cnn-lstm model

when i try to predict using my model i got this error

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)

here are my **code**

```
model_path = 'CCTV_10Frame_SGD_Model_1e4_b16_l21e2_Terbaru.h5' model = keras.models.load_model(model_path, compile = True)

vid = cv2.VideoCapture('Data16_116.mp4')


while vid.isOpened():
    ret, frame = vid.read()
    if ret == True:
      draw = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

      scale_percent = 20 # percent of original size
      width = int(frame.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
      height = width
      dim = (width, height)
      frame_set = cv2.resize(draw, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
      frame_set=np.arange(10*width*height*3).reshape(10,width, height, 3)
      frame_set.reshape(10, width, height, 3).shape
      boxes, scores, labels = model.predict_on_batch(
          np.expand_dims(frame_set, axis=0))
      boxes /= scale
      i_iterate = 0
      for box, score, label in zip(boxes[0], scores[0], labels[0]):
        if score < 0.5 or i_iterate > 0:
          break

        fps = 1/(start-prev_frame_time)
        prev_frame_time = start
        
        cv2.putText(draw, "%.2f" % fps, (7, 70), font,
                    1, (100, 255, 0), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
        

        color = label_color(label)
        b = box.astype(int)
        draw_box(draw, b, color=color)
        caption = "{} {:.3f}".format(classes[label], score)
        draw_caption(draw, b, caption)
        print("=================================")
        print("[INFO] Score : ", score)
        print("[INFO] Label : ", classes[label])
        i_iterate += 1

      print("=================================")
      cv2.imshow('Result', draw)  
      if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
      else:
        break

vid.release() cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

here are my model summary

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 10, 384, 384, 3)] 0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed (TimeDistri (None, 10, 128)           7717760   
_________________________________________________________________
lstm (LSTM)                  (None, 256)               394240    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 128)               32896     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 5)                 645       
=================================================================
Total params: 8,145,541
Trainable params: 8,142,789
Non-trainable params: 2,752
_________________________________________________________________
```

i would be grateful if someone can share if you have ever experience the same problem

Note : https://github.com/ljw20155136/Lip-reading-by-CNN-and-LSTM-architecture/blob/master/Lip%20Reading%20Tutorial%20Training.ipynb im using this github link to make the model, the difference are just im using my own dataset and the cnn model that i use are AlexNet(not using transfer learning i modified the github code and change the transfer learning model to alexNet model)

thank you before !

Comment: Not having full traceback, I'd guess `boxes, scores, labels = model.predict_on_batch( np.expand_dims(frame_set, axis=0))` is where you run into problem. Assuming model output to be of shape `(batch_size, 3)`, you might need to transpose output (`boxes, scores, labels = model.predict_on_batch(np.expand_dims(frame_set, axis=0)).T`)

Comment: hey @dm2 thank you for your response, i did try your response but now it got new error 
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

Comment: Could you post what your model summary/output shape looks like ?

Comment: You don't need to write every update in the comments (although these are not answers, it can provide background of what has been tried to people trying to answer), overcrowding isn't going to help. That being said, your model's last layer shows 5 outputs, you should unpack all 5, not just 3.

Comment: thank you for your correction, ah i thought it was too many to unpack for 3, the output from last layer was 5 are because my class for predition are 5, so i need to unpack all of it in my predict code?

Comment: Well, you shouldn't need to; it sounds like it's only outputting `labels`, where you expect it to output `boxes, scores, labels`. Is there any reason you expect these values?

Comment: so that when i show the video there'll be boxes for what i predict, scores like accuracy, f1, recall, or etc, and the labels(class) that i need for classification

Comment: https://github.com/ljw20155136/Lip-reading-by-CNN-and-LSTM-architecture/blob/master/Lip%20Reading%20Tutorial%20Training.ipynb im using this github link to make the model, the difference are just im using my own dataset and the cnn model that i use are AlexNet(not using transfer learning i modified the github code and change the transfer learning model to alexNet model),i didnt try it to a single datapoint/frame yet, will do that to see how it goes, thank you for your suggestion

Comment: Okay thank you for your suggestion ! will try using single frame first then